# How to get a 4x4 translation matrix from a vector in python

Tags: python, matrix, vector, translation

I want to get a 4x4 translation matrix from a vec3 in Python.
I don't know how I can do that correctly.

Can someboday explain what exactly needs to be done and how I can achieve this?

This is what I mean:
[image: img vector to matrix]
So basically the vector of T should become a 4x4 Matrix (like in the picture)

This is my code and the formula for the translation matrix:

```
# 4x4 Translations-Matrix T(-Px, -Py, -Pz) - needs to be 4x4 matrix
translation_matrix = (-P.x, -P.y, -P.z)
```

My Mat4x4 looks like this:

```
from __future__ import annotations


class Mat4x4:
def __init__(
        self,
        a11: float, a12: float, a13: float, a14: float,
        a21: float, a22: float, a23: float, a24: float,
        a31: float, a32: float, a33: float, a34: float,
        a41: float, a42: float, a43: float, a44: float,
):
    self.a11 = a11, self.a12 = a12, self.a13 = a13, self.a14 = a14
    self.a21 = a21, self.a22 = a22, self.a23 = a23, self.a24 = a24
    self.a31 = a31, self.a32 = a32, self.a33 = a33, self.a34 = a34
    self.a41 = a41, self.a42 = a42, self.a43 = a43, self.a44 = a44

# Matrix multiplication
def __mul__(self, other: Mat4x4) -> Mat4x4:
    return Mat4x4(
        self.a11 * other.a11 + self.a12 * other.a21 + self.a13 * other.a31 + self.a14 * other.a41,  # a11
        self.a11 * other.a12 + self.a12 * other.a22 + self.a13 * other.a32 + self.a14 * other.a42,  # a12
        self.a11 * other.a13 + self.a12 * other.a23 + self.a13 * other.a33 + self.a14 * other.a43,  # a13
        self.a11 * other.a14 + self.a12 * other.a24 + self.a13 * other.a34 + self.a14 * other.a44,  # a14

        self.a21 * other.a11 + self.a22 * other.a12 + self.a23 * other.a13 + self.a24 * other.a14,  # a21
        self.a21 * other.a21 + self.a22 * other.a22 + self.a23 * other.a23 + self.a24 * other.a24,  # a22
        self.a21 * other.a31 + self.a22 * other.a32 + self.a23 * other.a33 + self.a24 * other.a34,  # a23
        self.a21 * other.a41 + self.a22 * other.a42 + self.a23 * other.a43 + self.a24 * other.a44,  # a24

        self.a31 * other.a11 + self.a32 * other.a12 + self.a33 * other.a13 + self.a34 * other.a14,  # a31
        self.a31 * other.a21 + self.a32 * other.a22 + self.a33 * other.a23 + self.a34 * other.a24,  # a32
        self.a31 * other.a31 + self.a32 * other.a32 + self.a33 * other.a33 + self.a34 * other.a34,  # a33
        self.a31 * other.a41 + self.a32 * other.a42 + self.a33 * other.a43 + self.a34 * other.a44,  # a34

        self.a41 * other.a11 + self.a42 * other.a12 + self.a43 * other.a13 + self.a44 * other.a14,  # a41
        self.a41 * other.a21 + self.a42 * other.a22 + self.a43 * other.a23 + self.a44 * other.a24,  # a42
        self.a41 * other.a31 + self.a42 * other.a32 + self.a43 * other.a33 + self.a44 * other.a34,  # a43
        self.a41 * other.a41 + self.a42 * other.a42 + self.a43 * other.a43 + self.a44 * other.a44,  # a44
    )

# Add
def __add__(self, other: Mat4x4) -> Mat4x4:
    return Mat4x4(
        self.a11 + other.a11,  # a11
        self.a12 + other.a12,  # a12
        self.a13 + other.a13,  # a13
        self.a14 + other.a14,  # a14

        self.a21 + other.a21,  # a21
        self.a22 + other.a22,  # a22
        self.a23 + other.a23,  # a23
        self.a24 + other.a24,  # a24

        self.a31 + other.a31,  # a31
        self.a32 + other.a32,  # a32
        self.a33 + other.a33,  # a33
        self.a34 + other.a34,  # a34

        self.a41 + other.a41,  # a41
        self.a42 + other.a42,  # a42
        self.a43 + other.a43,  # a43
        self.a44 + other.a44,  # a44
    )

# Subtract
def __sub__(self, other: Mat4x4) -> Mat4x4:
    return Mat4x4(
        self.a11 - other.a11,  # a11
        self.a12 - other.a12,  # a12
        self.a13 - other.a13,  # a13
        self.a14 - other.a14,  # a14

        self.a21 - other.a21,  # a21
        self.a22 - other.a22,  # a22
        self.a23 - other.a23,  # a23
        self.a24 - other.a24,  # a24

        self.a31 - other.a31,  # a31
        self.a32 - other.a32,  # a32
        self.a33 - other.a33,  # a33
        self.a34 - other.a34,  # a34

        self.a41 - other.a41,  # a41
        self.a42 - other.a42,  # a42
        self.a43 - other.a43,  # a43
        self.a44 - other.a44,  # a44
    )

# Not Equal
def __ne__(self) -> Mat4x4:
    return Mat4x4(
        -self.a11,  # a11
        -self.a12,  # a12
        -self.a13,  # a13
        -self.a14,  # a14

        -self.a21,  # a21
        -self.a22,  # a22
        -self.a23,  # a23
        -self.a24,  # a24

        -self.a31,  # a31
        -self.a32,  # a32
        -self.a33,  # a33
        -self.a34,  # a34

        -self.a41,  # a41
        -self.a42,  # a42
        -self.a43,  # a43
        -self.a44,  # a44
    )

# Convert to string
def __str__(self) -> str:
    return (
            f'{self.a11} {self.a12} {self.a13} {self.a14}\n' +
            f'{self.a21} {self.a22} {self.a23} {self.a24}\n' +
            f'{self.a31} {self.a32} {self.a33} {self.a34}\n' +
            f'{self.a41} {self.a42} {self.a43} {self.a44}'
    )
```

And this is my code for Vec3:

```
import math

import numpy as np


class Vec3:
def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, z: float):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z

# Addition
def __add__(self, other):
    return Vec3(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z)

def __radd__(self, other):
    # other = self.convert2Vec3D(other)
    return self.__add__(other)

# Subtraktion
def __rsub__(self, other):
    # other = self.convert2Vec3D(other)
    return other.__sub__(self)

def __sub__(self, other):
    # other = self.convert2Vec3D(other)
    return Vec3(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y, self.z - other.z)

# Multiplikation
def __mul__(self, other):
    return Vec3(self.x * other.x + self.y * other.y + self.z * other.z)

def __rmul__(self, other):
    return self.__rmul__(self, other)

# Division
def __truediv__(self, other):
    return Vec3(self.x / other.x, self.y / other.y, self.z / other.z)
    # AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'x'

def __rtruediv__(self, other):
    # other = self.convert2Vec3D(other)
    return other.__rtruediv__(self)

# Kreuzprodukt
def cross(self, other):
    x1, y1, z1 = self.x, self.y, self.z
    x2, y2, z2 = other.x, other.y, other.z
    return Vec3(y1 * z2 - z1 * y2, z1 * x2 - x1 * z2, x1 * y2 - y1 * x2)

def __str__(self):
    return '(%g, %g, %g)' % (self.x, self.y, self.z)

# Absoluter Wert
def __abs__(self):
    absValue = math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2 + self.z ** 2)
    return Vec3(absValue, absValue, absValue)
```

I already tried to do some things like this

```
# translation_matrix = Mat4x4(a11=-P.x, a12=-P.y, a13=-P.z, a14=-P.x,
#                             a21=-P.x, a22=-P.y, a23=-P.z, a24=-P.x,
#                             a31=P.x, a32=P.y, a33=P.z, a34=P.x,
#                             a41=-P.x, a42=-P.y, a43=P.z, a44=-P.x)
```

But this approach doesn't seem right. So my question is: How can I properly get a 4x4 Matrix out of a Vector? It only needs to be printed out as a string, so I don't need it for drawing or something like that.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish here? I.e. what is your "4x4 translation matrix" in mathematical terms, compared to your 3d vector?

Comment: I added a image and further description to my question. Is it clearer now?
Basically I need to get a 4x4 matrix out of my Vector from the mathematical term for T(-Px, -Py, -Pz) 
I can add more information from the rest of my code, if that would help?

Comment: Do you understand how the math works, but need help with Python (and if so, with what, exactly?), or do you understand the Python bit but need help with the math? (By the way, `__ne__` is the not-equals method; negation is `__neg__`)

Comment: I am sorry if I have expressed myself in a misleading or difficult way. I am still a beginner in Python. 
Overall, my code must return a 4x4 projection matrix. And to derive this, I need among other things the 4x4 translation matrix which results from T(-Px, -Py, -Pz). 
Was this somewhat helpful for my problem? 

Thank you Ture Pålsson for your hint with __ne__ and __neg__!

Comment: So what is the general prescription going from a vector to the translation matrix? By the looks of it it seems that you have a 4x4 identity matrix and then you want to populate T_{3k} = v_k for k = 0...2. Is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is the transformation you are trying to do:

[image]

The easiest to achieve that would be something along the lines of:

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array((-1, -1, 1))
T = np.identity(n=4)
T[0:3,3] = -v
```

This yields what I *think* you want:

```
>>> T
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

All the magic happens in the last line, `T[0:3,3] = -v`, where you are assigning the three matrix elements: `T[0,3]=-v[0]`, `T[1,3]=-v[1]`, and `T[2,3]=-v[2]`. If you want to implement something similar within your own framework, you will need to use per-element assignments because your matrix is not a numpy ndarray. That said, I'd urge that you use ndarrays, they're much faster, more versatile and will save you from writing a *lot* of boilerplate code.